# Question on the definition of global points in category.

Tags: category-theory

Let $C$ be a category and let $1$ be a terminal object, a global point of of an object $X$ is a morphism $1 \to X$.

I don't have problems with the definition, but I am a little confused when it comes to the category $\bf{Sets}$. In $\bf{Sets}$ the terminal objects are all the singleton elements $\{ \ast \}$ and since for any set $A$ there are many morphisms $\{ \ast \} \to A$, then we have a lot of global points right? But in my book it says that any function $f: A \to B$ is determined by what it does with the global points of $A$. I understand that every element of $A$ is a global points of $A$, and then this makes sense, but isn't there many many more global points? Or are the global points of a set $A$ just the elements of $A$?

Please help to sort out my confusion.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to assume your concern is that you are worried that every element of $A$ gives rise to an arrow $a : 1 = \{*\} \to A$ it also gives rise to an arrow $a' : 1' = \{\star\} \to A$.  In other words, we have an arrow into $A$ for every pair of an element of $A$ and a terminal object.  This actually forms a proper class (unless $A = \emptyset$).

Basically, what's happening is we choose *one* particular object to be *the* terminal object which we notate as $1$ typically.  Then the global elements of $A$ are the elements of $\Gamma(A) \equiv \mathbf{Set}(1,A)$. That terminal objects are isomorphic means they are interchangeable with respect to all categorical properties.  In other words, there's no way to tell which choice we chose.  That they are further isomorphic by a *unique* isomorphism means if we *do* want to make a different choice, everything transforms in a *canonical* way.  In other words, we have no choice in how things change when we make a different choice for *the* terminal object.

So "global elements" doesn't mean arrows from *all* terminal objects, just arrows from one, and which it is doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

Global points in $A$ are essentially just elements of $A$, in that a map $*\to A$ is determined by a choice of singleton $*$ and the image $a$ of the map. There are many singletons, but they're all isomorphic, so we rarely pay attention to he distinction between them.